# Why does json.dump produce line endings in vscode?

Tags: python, json

```
with open('weather.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(response.text, json_file, separators=(", ", ": "), sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=True)

weather.json = "{\"meta\":{\"exec_time\":0.021,\"generated\":\"2020-07-04 19:07:54\"},\"data\":[{\"id\":\"KHBI0\",\"name\":{\"en\":\"Asheboro \\/ Cedar Grove\"},\"active\":true,\"distance\":8.4}]}"
```

i tried pd.read_json with ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

also tried replacing

```
data = weather.json
data.replace('\\', '')
```

and retrieve string, yet still vscode does not recognize as json file, and does not pretty print

```
ouput: {"meta":{"exec_time":0.021,"generated":"2020-07-04 19:07:54"},"data":[{"id":"KHBI0","name":{"en":"Asheboro / Cedar Grove"},"active":true,"distance":8.4}]}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! In order to get the best answer from community, please refer to ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article and always format your code if you include some in your question!

Comment: response.json()

Answer (score 2):

`json.dump(response.text)` ... why are you serializing text?

You serialized a string, which represents JSON already, **as a JSON string**. So it will get deserialized as a string...

Consider:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = '{"foo":42}'
>>> type(data)
<class 'str'>
>>> data["foo"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>> serialized = json.dumps(data)
>>> print(serialized)
"{\"foo\":42}"
```

So when you *deserialize* it:

```
>>> deserialized = json.loads(serialized)
>>> deserialized
'{"foo":42}'
>>> type(deserialized)
<class 'str'>
```

You almost certainly just want:

```
with open('weather.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Note, all of this has nothing to do with VS Code.

Comment: Just curious, did you really understand any of that question? :)